# How to plot binomial variable percentage bar plot with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, bar-chart, percentage

I'm plotting a binomial variable (0/1) called "aborted" in the following script:

```
`ggplot(sab2, aes(x=locality,fill=factor(aborted))) + geom_bar() + scale_fill_manual() + scale_fill_grey(labels = c("aborted","alive")) + xlab("") + ylab("N empty fruits per plant") + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Fruits vitality")) + facet_grid(~year) + theme_bw() + theme(legend.position = "bottom",  panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"), panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "white"),  axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5))`
```

and this was the result:

[image]

What could I change in my code if I want to plot only the % of aborted (the "0" level of the "aborted" factor)? 
I could obtain a plot similar to the follow (but with % of aborted):

[image]

thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `stat_summary` to calculate the mean value of `aborted`, which is just the percentage aborted when `aborted` takes on values of 0 or 1. Then you can also use `stat_summary` with `mean_cl_boot` to get a bootstrapped 95% confidence interval. Here's an example with fake data:

```
library(scales)

set.seed(389)
sab2 = data.frame(locality=rep(1:6,each=100), aborted=sample(0:1, 600, replace=TRUE))

ggplot(sab2, aes(factor(locality), aborted)) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="bar", fill="grey70") +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, geom="errorbar", width=0.2) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format(), limits=c(0,1)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Points might be better than a barplot here:

```
ggplot(sab2, aes(factor(locality), aborted)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, geom="errorbar", width=0.2) +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="point", shape=21, fill="red", size=2) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format(), limits=c(0,1)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Or use the percentage values as the point markers:

```
ggplot(sab2, aes(factor(locality), aborted)) +
  stat_summary(fun.data=mean_cl_boot, geom="errorbar", width=0.2, colour="grey60") +
  stat_summary(fun.y=mean, geom="text", size=3, colour="red",
               aes(label=paste0(sprintf("%1.1f", ..y..*100),"%"))) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent_format(), limits=c(0,1)) +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. Your fake dataset work, but not mine.. The error message is: "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale". This  is the structure of my dataset: data.frame': 1680 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ year    : Factor w/ 2 levels "2013","2014": 1 1 ...
 $ locality: Ord.factor w/ 6 levels "A"<"B"<..: 5 5 ...
 $ plot    : Factor w/ 98 levels "CM1","CM10","CM11",..: 1 1 ...
 $ seeds   : int  3 0 4 6 2 5 6 1 5 5 ...
 $ aborted : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 2 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...

Comment: It looks like it's because `aborted` is a factor. It needs to be numeric or integer with values 0 or 1 to get percentages plotted by the method in my answer. That's what the `Discrete value supplied to continuous scale` error means. You're running `scale_y_continuous`, but your y-value is a categorical (i.e., factor) variable).

Comment: thank you very much! now I can work to solve my problem, cheers!